# Как сделать кнопку типа submit картинкой

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать, чтобы вместо невзрачной кнопки типа submit в форме была картинка, но функция кнопки та же?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" style="background-image: url(image.png);" />
```

Comment: Уже разобрался, но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

background-image

Comment: Соррь не заметил ответ выше. Используй background-image и всё будет гуд.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit">
    <image src="<url>">
    а можно и кучу других тегов какие хотите
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" src="{url}" name="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

В `css` это можно сделать так:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    background:url('image.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

попробуй так: `src="img/bg.gif"`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: И куда автор вопроса должен вставлять этот фрагмент?